# Inverse gamma convergence in probability

Tags: gamma-distribution, convergence

I am trying to prove the consistency of MLE for a beta distribution. The problem now reduces to the following:

Assume $Y=\frac n X$ and $X$ ~ Gamma(n,$\frac 1 \theta$), prove that $Y$ converges to $\theta$ in probability when $n$ goes to infinity.

I set up the proof by the definition of convergence in probability but cannot prove it.

Comment: What definition did you use?  What prevents you from carrying out the proof?

Comment: The limit of $\rm{P}(|Y-\theta|<\epsilon)$ is 1 for any $\epsilon > 0$ when $n$ goes to infinity. Basically, this probability can be calculated as the difference of CDF of a gamma distribution, but it is hard for me to find a closed form of that CDF when integrate from $\frac n {\theta + \epsilon}$ to $\frac n {\theta - \epsilon}$.

Comment: You might want to try to approximate that probability with a normal probability, which in the limit is exact of course.

Comment: @JohnK Thanks for your suggestion, I know that Gamma can be approximated by normal when $n$ is large. But I am not comfortable with this approximation because this is not the classical approach of proof for convergence in prob.

Comment: It's a legit method of proof since we are letting $n$ go to infinity. In any case, if you are not comfortable with that try using Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: @JohnK In this case $\theta$ is not the expectation value of $Y$, could U specify how to apply Chebyshev's Inequality?

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality does not require that the constant is the mean. You can prove that $$ E\left(Y - c \right)^2 \geq a^2 P\left[ | Y - c | \geq a \right] $$ for any constants $a>0$ and $c$.

Comment: Also, can you please specify which parameterization of the gamma distribution you are using?

Comment: @JohnK Thanks, I have carried out the proof using Chebyshev's Inequality. My convention is the shape and scale one. i.e. Gamma($\alpha$, $\beta$) so that EX is $\alpha \beta$ and VarX is $\alpha \beta^2$.

Comment: @JohnK Also, I am thinking about your earlier tip by using Normal approx. It worked well. However, I still don't think that is a legit one. My logic is by using Normal approx you are applying CLT which is sth converging in distribution. Here, we are trying to prove sth converging in probability which is a stronger level of convergence.

Comment: It might put you at ease to know that in case there is convergence to a constant, convergence in probability and convergence in distribution are completely equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, what I approximated here is indeed using the PDF of normal to replace the PDF of Gamma to calculate $P(|Y-\theta|)\geq \epsilon)$ analytically. So, not a constant, right? Or I misunderstood your "approx"?

Answer (score 2):

This is also a direct consequence of the Law of Large numbers: if $X_n\sim\mathcal{G}(n,\theta)$, $X$ can be written as
$$X_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n\qquad Y_i\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{E}(\theta)$$
Therefore,
$$\dfrac{X_n}{n}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{n}\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{E}[Y_1]=\dfrac{1}{\theta}$$
and thus
$$\dfrac{n}{X_n}\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using Chebyshev's Inequality to prove that:
$$\rm{P} (|Y-\theta| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon^2} E[(Y-\theta)^2]$$
Since Y is equal to $\frac n X$ where $X$ is a Gamma distributed random variable ($X$ ~ Gamma ($n$,$\frac 1 \theta$)), one can calculate that:
$$E[(Y-\theta)^2]=\frac {n^2\theta^2} {(n-1)(n-2)} - \frac {2n\theta^2} {n-1} + \theta^2$$
which goes to 0 when $n$ goes to infinity. This demonstrates that $$\rm{P} (|Y-\theta| \geq \epsilon)=0$$
when $n$ goes to infinity. Therefore, Y is a consistent estimator of $\theta$ (Y converge to $\theta$ in probability).